# Getting an error while Updating WCF Service Reference

Tags: wcf

I got an error like this.

> There was an error downloading http://localhost:5705/UserService.svc
>   Unable to connect Remote Server No Connection could be made because
>   the target machine actively refused 127.0.0.1:5705 Metadata contains a
>   reference that cant be Resolved
>   'http://localhost:5705/UserService.svc' could not connect to
>   'http://localhost:5705/UserService.svc'
>   TCP error code 10064:No Connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   127.0.0.1:5705, enable to connect
>   Remote Server No Connection could be made because the target machine actively refused 127.0.0.1:5705

Comment: Is your server running and check the port settings maybe your service is running on a different port or the port is blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is normally 4 reasons for this:

- The service is not running
- The meta data exchange is not enabled
- No mex endpoint is defined
- port is blocked on firewall